How far is too far for metal drip edge to be away from fascia?
I am replacing a water-damaged piece of fascia.  Below are before and after photos.
My question: how much of a gap between the metal drip edge and the fascia board is too much?
Previously, there was a furring strip immediately behind the drip edge.  There was ~1/8" gap between the drip edge and the furring strip.  Both the furring strip and the fascia to which it was attached have suffered water damage.

On This Old House, they suggest a much larger gap between drip edge and fascia:

Silva recommends installing the drip edge so the edge of the roof is 1 1/2 to 1 3/4 inches away from your fascia board. This way, water can drop freely instead of seeping back into the fascia. “It won’t drop if it does get blown in there from wind, but it’s really not going to be surface tension,” Silva says.

[note: the 1 1/2 - 1 3/4 measurement includes distance that shingles overhang drip edge, so distance between lower portion of drip edge and fascia should be less than that]
I slid a new fascia board in without a furring strip, and there is ~1" between drip edge and fascia.  This is comparable to what This Old House recommends...but it seems like a lot to me!  Perhaps that is simply because it is not something I am used to.  It does make sense to me that this would work better for water coming off the roof, but wind-blown water does concern me.

I am thinking of replacing the furring strip as well, but I will make it narrower so that it does not extend below the drip edge.  Although...would this step not really be worth the trouble?

1 1/2 to 1 3/4 inches ?  That must be a typo.   Or, it describes the overall amount of roof edge.  Silva was in a video and he used his little finger to create the gap between the fascia and metal drip edge.

The article describes the edge of the roof being that far away--meaning the shingle line or the outer metal hem--not the bottom flange.

Yes, it's the roof edge.  Shingles extend beyond drip edge, drip edge is spaced from fascia.  Together, that adds up to that distance.  In my case, the bottom flange is closer to 3/4" - 1"

Opinions vary on this. Mine is that there should be no gap at all*, and that's how I've always installed it, pressing it lightly against the fascia before nailing it down. Here's why.

The bottom flange of the drip edge is a critical support component. Without it being in contact with the fascia, the component can sag, resulting in a rounded appearance along the bottom of the roof.

The gap looks bad. It's never uniform and parallel. It looks like a mistake to my eye.

If the drip edge is functioning properly, the bottom flange won't have runoff occurring anyway. The shingles should extend beyond it slightly (1/2" to 3/4"), and any water getting below that should detach on the edge hem. If it doesn't, the edge was probably installed at too shallow a slope. This can happen when framing is sloppy or it's pulled too tight and the bottom flange lifts it.

Fascia is going to get wet anyway in a rainstorm. It's silly to assume you can keep it dry when water's being blown around. While an argument can be made that a gap allows airflow and quicker drying, the same would be necessary at many other places, such as butt joints and corner miters. The argument doesn't hold water, to my mind.

Wooden fascias should be well sealed or wrapped anyway. Metal or vinyl wraps aren't very expensive, are easy to install, and dramatically extend the useful life of any wooden fascia. I'm not sure why anyone would go to the trouble and expense of replacing fascia and not wrap it.


If you do decide to leave a gap, I'd install something to support the edge; I don't like droopy roofs. Even occasional small blocks or ribs would help.
* Other than that created by the small bend in the bottom of the flange, which varies with its angle and roof pitch.

The article describes the edge of the roof being that far away--meaning the shingle line or the outer metal hem--not the bottom flange. Emphasis mine.

Silva recommends installing the drip edge so the edge of the roof is 1 1/2 to 1 3/4 inches away from your fascia board.

Assuming about a 1" metal protrusion and a 1/2" to 3/4" shingle overhang, that's exactly where you'd be.

If it is away, rain will be blown back under the shingles and the sheathing and rot. If it is flush it won't plus if the fascia is clad, it is water tight. Most of the rain goes off the roof edge depending on the pitch.
